# Convert a String into a List of Tuples

Tags: python, string, list, tuples

I want to write a function that receives a string as a parameter and then converts it into a list of tuples.

String with dummy data:

```py
locations_data = """
NewYork 37.936389°N 23.947222°E
London  37.936389°N 23.947222°E
Berlin  37.936389°N 23.947222°E
Milano  37.936389°N 23.947222°E
```

So far I know that I have to loop over the string splitter by `°E` but I'm getting confused when I have to separate each "rows" data.

```py
for i in locations_data.split("°E")
```

Desired output:

```py
locations = [
(NewYork, 37.936389, 23.947222),
(London, 37.936389, 23.947222),
(Berlin, 37.936389, 23.947222),
(Milano, 37.936389, 23.947222)
]
```

Comment: Use `splitlines()` to split it into sepate lines. Then use `split()` to split each line at whitespace.

Comment: Thank you. But I have to split more than whitespace for each line.

Comment: No you don't. You can remove the degrees after splitting.;

Answer (score 2):

Use `split()` to split each line into 3 fields. Remove the degree symbols and convert them to floats, then put them into tuples.

```
import re

locations = []
for line in locations_data.splitlines():
    city, lat, lon = line.split()
    lat = float(re.sub(r'°[NS]$', '', lat))
    lon = float(re.sub(r'°[EW]$', '', lon))
    locations.append((city, lat, lon))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this way to solve the problem.

```
locations = list(map(lambda x: tuple(x.split()), locations_data.split("°E")[:4]))
print(locations)
```

`locations_data.split("°E")[:4]` here this `[:4]` part is use to remove the last empty string.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a regex. Then you have several options:

`re.split`:

```
import re
[re.split('(?:°[NSEW])?\s+', s) for s in locations_data.splitlines()]
```

`re.findall`:

```
import re
re.findall('(\w+)\s+([\d.]+).. ([\d.]+)..', locations_data)
```

output:

```
[('NewYork', '37.936389', '23.947222'),
 ('London', '37.936389', '23.947222'),
 ('Berlin', '37.936389', '23.947222'),
 ('Milano', '37.936389', '23.947222')]
```

to have floats:

```
[(a, float(b), float(c))
 for a,b,c in re.findall('(\w+)\s+([\d.]+).. ([\d.]+)..', locations_data)]
```

output:

```
[('NewYork', 37.936389, 23.947222),
 ('London', 37.936389, 23.947222),
 ('Berlin', 37.936389, 23.947222),
 ('Milano', 37.936389, 23.947222)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Dirty but effective

```
lines = locations_data.split('\n')
locations = []

for line in lines:
    if len(line) > 0:
        my_tuple = ()
        
        for val in line.split(' '):
            if len(val) > 0:
                my_tuple = my_tuple + (val.replace('°N','').replace('°E',''),)

        locations.append(my_tuple)

print(locations)
# [('NewYork', '37.936389', '23.947222'), ('London', '37.936389', '23.947222'), ('Berlin', '37.936389', '23.947222'), ('Milano', '37.936389', '23.947222')]
```